# Running libgdx html

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to understand this great lib. when I'm trying to run html with run as>web application I get errors. here's the console text and gwt definition file.

```
Loading modules
com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition
Loading inherited module 'com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition'
[ERROR] Line 3: Unexpected exception while processing element 'module'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef$ModuleType.LİBRARY
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef$ModuleType.valueOf(ModuleDef.java:70)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema.__module_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:1432)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Gwtdefinition xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
<inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
<inherits name='MyGdxGame' />
<entry-point class='com.me.mygdxgame.client.GwtLauncher' />
<set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../my-gdx-game-android/assets" />
</module>
```

MyGdxGame.gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <source path="com/me/mygdxgame" />
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week at the end i've discovered the problem. If you are using non-english operatin system gwt fails.

For eclipse, just add;

-Duser.language=en

to run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Please post MyGdxGame.gwt.xml in your main project.

Your gwtdefinition file seems okay, but since it is calling the other xml file,

```
<inherits name='MyGdxGame' />
```

I suppose the error might be present there.