# GWT Hello World ; java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.ModuleType.LİBRARY

Tags: eclipse, exception, gwt, compilation, arguments

I only want to compile my HelloWorld **GWT** example; but in my first example i take this issue

Windows 32 Ultimate- Turkish, Eclipse Mars,

Comment: Loading inherited module 'com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld'
   [ERROR] Line 8: Unexpected exception while processing element 'module'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.ModuleType.LİBRARY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439967/running-libgdx-html), your Turkish OS might be the problem.

Add `-Duser.language=en` to your run configuration.

Comment: Note that this has been fixed for GWT 2.7 (luckily enough, there's a Turk developer in the GWT Team at Google ;-) )