# GWT Compiler fails

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I try to choose the Google compiler for the automatically generated code, I get the following error;

```
Loading inherited module 'com.example.Dropbox.Dropbox'
   [ERROR] Line 8: Unexpected exception while processing element 'module'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.ModuleType.LİBRARY
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef$ModuleType.valueOf(ModuleDef.java:70)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema.__module_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:1432)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
   [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
   [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
```

This is apparently a language error, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086901/gwt-hello-world-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-enum-constant-com-googl) but I changed eclipse.ini to this:

```
-startup
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-install
C:/Users/Pc/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/javaw.exe

-vmargs
-Duser.language=en_US
```

Yet the error persists. What should I do?

Comment: Which version if GWT are you using? I thought those things had been fixed some time ago.

Comment: 2.6.0, since that's the one that as Eclipse plug-in. I'm not using 2.7.0 with Maven.

Comment: Download GWT 2.7.0 SDK from http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html and configure your Eclipse to use it.

Comment: Yeah, I waited for 8 hours and the download for Eclipse just failed. Thanks for the suggestion, though.